# jQuery Hide Div(s) on focus of drop down menu or text (live search) input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Can anyone help me?  I'm trying to hide the #hideme div when the a user clicks the drop down menu (to select something) or puts the focus on the text field.  Thanks!

```
   #hideme {
     background:#ccc;
    }

    <script>
    $(function(){
       $('#skill_select').click(function(){
            $('#hideme').hide();
        });
    }):
    </script>
    <select>
            <option selected="selected">Pick from the list</option>
            <option>Option One</option>
            <option>Option Two</option>
    </select>
    or <input type="text" value="type something">
    <br/><br/>
    <div id="hideme">Hide Me Please</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the select and textbox ID's:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option selected="selected">Pick from the list</option>
    <option>Option One</option>
    <option>Option Two</option>
</select>
or <input type="text" value="type something" id="myText">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideMe() {
        $('#hideme').hide();
    }

    $('#mySelect').change(hideMe);
    $('#myText').focus(hideMe);
</script>
```

Comment: @webwrks Remove the "double colon" at the end of your code (posted before in the comments). see http://jsfiddle.net/Pc5Pz/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all you want to do is hide.

```
$('select, input').click(function() {
        $('#hideme').hide();
    });
```

If you want to show the div back again when user clicked outside select or input, then do this

```
$('select,input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#hideme').hide();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#hideme').show();
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/2p6Y7/2/

Don't use select, input. Create id's for each of them and select them by there id.

Comment: This works Hussein, but I was trying to do it on focus and change like the Scrum Meister did it...why is The Scrum's not working?